# Multi compound assignment operator?

Tags: c#

Why the result of the following code is *x = y = z = 1* ?

```
int x = 0, y= 0, z = 0;
x += y += z += 1;
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", x, y, z);
```

Comment: Why do you even write such code? Or is this pure academic question?

Comment: Most likely because it is processed Right-to-Left. `z += 1` (z = 1), `y += z` (y = 1), etc.

Comment: It's equivalent to `z += 1; y += z; x += y;` (right to left)

Comment: `z += 1` evaluates to one. `y += 1` evaluates to one. `x += 1` evaluates to- guess - `5`? No, one of course?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have found out it while i coding. I only know why. The code should not use, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment statements actually evaluate to a value. The value that it evaluates to is equal to the right hand side of the assignment statement.

So `x = 5;` evaluates to `5`.

Now let's dissect this:

```
x += y += z += 1;
```

First we replace the shorthand `+=` to make things clearer (note that assignment operators are right-associative):

```
x += y += (z = z + 1)
x += (y = y + (z = z + 1))
x = x + (y = y + (z = z + 1))
```

Now, we evaluate! Keep in mind that assignments evaluate to the value of the right hand side!

```
x = x + (y = y + (z = z + 1))
x = x + (y = y + (z = 1))
x = x + (y = y + 1) // z is now 1
x = x + (y = 1)
x = x + 1 // y is now 1
x = 1
// x is now 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because:

- `z (0)` is increased by `1` (thus:
  `0 + 1 = 1`)
- `y (0)` is increased by `z`, which is the result of the previous operation (`z += 1 -> 1`), hence `y + z = 0 + 1 = 1`
- `x (0)` is increased by `y`, which is the result of the previous operation (`y += z -> 1`), hence `x + y = 0 + 1 = 1`

Even if the operations are chained, this doesn't mean they are evaluated all at once. They are always performed sequentially, from the right to the left, provided their operators have the same priority (and this is the case). Splitting your code into multiple lines following the [evaluation order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) and simplifying the notations can probably provide a better insight on what's going on:

```
Int32 x = 0;
Int32 y = 0;
Int32 z = 0;

z = z + 1; // z = 0 + 1 = 1
y = y + z; // y = 0 + 1 = 1
x = x + y; // x = 0 + 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As all your operators have the same priority, you need some order of execution. As seen on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ibrary/2bxt6kc4.aspx) that order for the `+=`-operator is from *right to left*. In contrast `3 + 4 + 5` will first evaluate `3 + 4` and then add `5` to the result, as the `+`-operator is *left to right* evaluated.

The same happens in your example. First `z += 1` will evaluate to one. This result (not `z` itself) is passed to the next `+=`-operator, so you get `y += 1` which itself evaluates to one and is assigned to the operator `+=` again.

An operator is basically nothing different than a simple method-call, as you can indicate by its signature:

```
public static int operator += (int c1, intc2) { ... }
```

So all you do is to call that "method" with the result of a previous call like this:

```
int.CallAssignPlus(ref x, int.CallIassgnPlus(ref y, int.CallAsignPlus(ref z, 1)));
```

Of course that code isn´t how it´s actually translated to IL, however it shows how it works.

So what´s important here is not actually the fact, that you have variables that are assigned to anything, but rather that even the result of an assignment is an expression which can be used in any other statement. Having said this `z +=1` is just a statement that has a value. Thus not `z` is passed to `y`, but the value of that statement (which however is equal to the value of `z`).

Comment: @Tiniki: no, it'll be `(3 + 4) + 5`